# How can I make or use a pattern like the newest gmail (for android v5.0)

Tags: android, gmail

As we all know,google release the android L，and the gmail went into more beautiful.Now I want to use this pattern like the pic,I searched it everywhere,github included, only to find that nothing.
THX deeply in advanced! Here is the pic:[image]

---

oh!I'm sorry,I forget to mention that the new refresh layout,could you see the circle within a Curved arrow.swipe the screen down,and it begin to refresh,maybe it's s new swipefreshlayout,thx!

Comment: checkout [material-design-theme](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html),[appcompat-v21](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/) and [android-ui by markushi](https://github.com/markushi/android-ui)

Comment: Please explain completely and precisely what "a pattern like the newest gmail" means. What specifically out of the screenshot are you looking for?

Comment: uh...i'm sorry,i forget to mention that the pattern is the refresh layout,the curving arrow as you can see from the sreenshoot.thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the new SwipeRefreshLayout class that is included in the latest support library. The implementation is exactly the same as the old support swipeRefresh layout

Comment: New swiperefresh also fixes some bugs with scrolling I had!

Comment: yes,but do you know how to swipe up to load more by using it?

Answer (score 0):

Here an overview:
http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html

Here is explained how to use it: https://developer.android.com/training/material/index.html

Comment: Thank you,but it's not the answer i want,I forget to mention the refresh layout.I want to use the gmail refresh layout.